# Restoring pgsql dump file on window's command prompt

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I was trying to use **psql** command to restore a pgsql file to a newly created database using the following command:

```
psql -d xerus -f C:\Users\'Rishikesh Bhattacharya'\desktop\xerus_backup.pgsql
```

It threw the error that:

```
psql invalid command \
```

I think this error is because usually psql terminal commands begin with ''. So I tried to change the back slashes in path to the file, to forward slashes. It worked after that change.

```
psql -d xerus -f C:/Users/'Rishikesh Bhattacharya'/desktop/xerus_backup.pgsql
```

But I fail to understand how is it possible for the psql command to interact with OS, when this change is made?

Comment: Try  `-f "C:/Users/Rishikesh Bhattacharya/desktop/xerus_backup.pgsql"`

Comment: Postgres knows what OS it is running on and by use of `#ifndef WIN32` makes the change from "/" to "\" internally. At the moment I cannot remember/find the exact code where that happens.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. That's helpful.